# Calculate The Following Probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, recursion

**Given the following Question:**

The possibility to win contest $A$ is $P1$, and the possibility to win contest $B$ it's $P2$.

We buy tickets for contest $A$ until we win for the **first** time, then We buy tickets for contest $B$ until we win for the **first** time, then again we but tickets for contest $A$ until we win the the **first** time and so on.

In other words, We try $A$ multiple times until we win once, then We go $B$ until we win etc.

Let $P(n)$ be the possibility that the $n$th ticket purchased is for contest $A$, find a recursive function for $P(n)$.

---

What I have done:

1. First, since we are talking about **first** win we can use the [Geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).
2. I figured out that in order for ticket $n$ to be for contest $A$ then before that we are supposed to win even number in contest $A$ (Not sure if this helps at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say probability of winning contest $A$ is $p$ and contest $B$ is $q$ (instead of using $P1, P2)$.

$P(1) = 1$

$P(n) = P(n-1)(1-p) + (1-P(n-1))q \,$ ($n \gt 1$).

I validated this for a few low values of $n$.

$P(2) = (1-p)$

$P(3) = (1-p)^2 + p q$

$P(4) = (1-p)^3 + p(1-q)q + (1-p)pq + pq(1-p) = (1-p)^3 + p(1-q)q + 2 (1-p)pq$

...

Comment: I gave the recurrence relation first and then tried to show that it worked for $2, 3, 4$ etc. I wrote $P(2), P(3), P(4)$ based on all possibilities that are there. Then if I apply recurrence relation, it matches.